# Заполнение таблицы данными из другой таблицы

Tags: sql

Запрос с накоплением суммы.
Есть таблица `Ostatok_vremy`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как получить таблицу с накоплением по ID_Tovar, ID_Obratv выступает в роли времени.  Наподобие как тут [Запрос с накоплением суммы - MS Access](http://www.cyberforum.ru/ms-access/thread1089805.html)

На данном этапе запрос всё суммирует в одно. А не по отдельности для каждого. И как суммировать еще поле kolizestvo

```
 SELECT Ostatok_vremy.ID_Obratv, ID_Tovar, (SELECT SUM(Summa) FROM 
 Ostatok_vremy WHERE ID_Obratv<=Ostatok_vremy.ID_Obratv AND 
 ID_Tovar=Ostatok_vremy.ID_Tovar) AS [Сум_b_групп_по_а]
 FROM Ostatok_vremy
 ORDER BY ID_Obratv, ID_Tovar
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добрый день. Есть [статья в W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) по поводу этой темы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT t.id_tovar, sum(t.summa) AS so, sum(t.kolizestvo) AS ko
FROM Ostatok_vremy as t LEFT JOIN Ostatok_vremy AS t_1 ON t.id_obtativ < t_1.id_obtativ
and t.id_tovar=t_1.id_tovar
GROUP BY t.id_tovar;